# How does one convert a stringified regex literal back into a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, literals

For example I got a string in client from the server:

```
"/hello\s{0,1}[-_.]{0,1}world|ls\b/gim"
```

In client I wants to convert this string into an regex object. I tried

```
new RegExp("/hello\s{0,1}[-_.]{0,1}world|ls\b/gim")
```

But this will not work, the returned object is

```
/\/hellos{0,1}[-_.]{0,1}world|ls\/gim/
```

To summarize:
What I want is:

```
/hello\s{0,1}[-_.]{0,1}world|ls\b/gim.test('hello world') //true (correct behavior)
```

However this is not working:

```
new RegExp("/hello\s{0,1}[-_.]{0,1}world|ls\b/gim").test('hello world') //false
```

What's the correct way to doing this?

Comment: heh: `eval("/hello\\s{0,1}[-_.]{0,1}world|ls\\b/gim").test('hello world')`

Comment: Since you were given regex syntax (not string syntax), you can't use that directly with the regex constructor.  You could use it with `eval()`.

Answer (score 6):

The `RegExp` constructor takes two arguments. The first is the literal source/pattern to match (essentially the stuff between the outer `/` in a regex literal); the second is the flags to be set on that expression (e.g. `gim` in your example). I defined a helper function for you below that converts strings in your format to regular expressions. Ironically, I ended up using another regex to do so.

```js
function regexFromString (string) {
    const match = /^([^/]*)(\/([a-z]*))?$/.exec(string)
    if(match.length <= 3)
        return new RegExp(match[1])
    return new RegExp(match[1], match[3])
}

var string = '/hello\\s{0,1}[-_.]{0,1}world|ls\\b/gim'

var regex = regexFromString(string)

console.log(regex instanceof RegExp) //=> true
console.log(regex)
console.log(regex.test('hello world')) //=> true
```

Comment: why not pass a regexp and spare the extra escaping? does your script handle embeded slashes? (no ^|$)

Comment: 1) In OP's words: *"I got a string in client from the server"*. He does not get a regular expression; therefore, I do not start with one either in my snippet. 2) I see what you mean about the slashes. Almost missed that, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: The following matches properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69627874/9156535

Answer (score 1):

Using the `RegExp` constructor is a little different, here is what I believe you are looking for:

```
var x = new RegExp('hello\\s{0,1}[-_.]{0,1}world|ls\\b', 'gim').test("hello world");

console.log(x);
```

returns true

Answer (score 0):

***Late answer***

An approach which is based on regex itself would [capture](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) from any provided stringified regex literal the expession's `body` and its optional `flags` part.

The regex itself could look like this ... [`/^\/(?<body>.*)\/(?<flags>[gimsuy]*)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/Ek881d/2) ... and a failsafe approach which uses this regex then might look like the beneath one ...

```js
// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/Ek881d/2]

function regexFromString(str) {
  const {
    body,
    flags,
  } = String(str)
    .match(/^\/(?<body>.*)\/(?<flags>[gimsuy]*)$/)
    ?.groups || {};

  return RegExp(body, (body && flags));
}

console.log(
  "regexFromString(String(/hello\s{0,1}[-_.]{0,1}world|ls\b/gim)).test('hello world') ? ",

  regexFromString(
    String(/hello\s{0,1}[-_.]{0,1}world|ls\b/gim)
  ).test('hello world')
);
console.log(
  "regexFromString('') ...",
  regexFromString('')
);

console.log(
  regexFromString('/foo/'),
  'this isfoook'.split(regexFromString('/foo/'))
);
console.log(
  regexFromString('/foo\\/bar/ig'),
  'this isfoo/barok'.split(regexFromString('/foo\\/bar/ig'))
);
console.log(
  regexFromString('/foo/bar/ig'),
  'this isfoo/barok'.split(regexFromString('/foo/bar/ig'))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If a server provides regex to the client, the following Regex matches another Regex and separates body from flags to properly reconstruct it.

```js
function regexFromString(string) {
    const matchFlags = /^(.*)(\/([a-z]*))$/.exec(string)
    if (matchFlags && matchFlags.length >= 4)
        return new RegExp(matchFlags[1], matchFlags[3])

    return new RegExp(string)
}

var regex = regexFromString("^[a-z]{6}[0-9a-z]{2}([0-9a-z]{3})$/i")
console.log(regex.test("NtSbDeB1XxX"))
```